# Difference between functions and Markov chains for estimation

Tags: measure-theory, optimization, estimation

Given two random variables $X$ and $Y$ on two alphabet $\mathcal X$ and $\mathcal Y$, I'm interested in minimizing the expected distortion $\mathbb E[d(X,\hat X)]$ for $\hat X$ taking values in alphabet $\hat{\mathcal X}$ in two different scenarios. The first one is $X-Y-\hat X$ forms a Markov chain and the second one is $\hat X=\hat x(Y)$ for some function $\hat x:\mathcal Y\rightarrow \hat{\mathcal X}$.

I am very tempted to say that
\begin{align*}
\inf_{X-Y-\hat X} \mathbb E[d(X,\hat X)] = \inf_{\hat x:\mathcal Y\rightarrow \hat{\mathcal X} } \mathbb E[d(X,\hat x(Y))]
\end{align*}

But cannot prove it in general (so it may of course be false), it is trivial to have an inequality here since it always holds that $X-Y-\hat x(Y)$ is a Markov chain. Does anyone have insights about that, maybe a couter example or a proof ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a proof that your fact is true for the case $\mathcal{X}, \mathcal{Y}, \mathcal{\hat{X}}$ are finite sets.

Let $(X,Y,\hat{X})$ be random variables that form a Markov chain $X\rightarrow Y \rightarrow\hat{X}$. Then 
\begin{align}
E[d(X,\hat{X})] &= \sum_{y \in \mathcal{Y}}\sum_{\hat{x} \in \mathcal{\hat{X}}}\sum_{x \in \mathcal{X}}  P[Y=y,X=x,\hat{X}=\hat{x}]d(x,\hat{x})\\
&=\sum_{y \in \mathcal{Y}}P[Y=y]\sum_{\hat{x} \in \mathcal{\hat{X}}}P[\hat{X}=\hat{x}|Y=y]\sum_{x \in \mathcal{X}} P[X=x|Y=y]d(x,\hat{x})\\
&\geq \sum_{y \in \mathcal{Y}}P[Y=y]\min_{c\in\mathcal{\hat{X}}}\left[\sum_{x \in \mathcal{X}} P[X=x|Y=y]d(x,c)\right]
\end{align}
So we can define a function $c:\mathcal{Y}\rightarrow \mathcal{\hat{X}}$ by 
$$ c(y) = \arg\min_{c \in \mathcal{\hat{X}}} \left[\sum_{x \in \mathcal{X}} P[X=x|Y=y]d(x,c)\right]$$
breaking ties in some arbitrary (deterministic) way.  Then 
\begin{align}
E[d(X,\hat{X})] &\geq \sum_{y \in \mathcal{Y}} P[Y=y]\sum_{x \in \mathcal{X}} P[X=x|Y=y]d(x,c(y))\\
&= E[d(X, c(Y))]\\
&\geq \inf_{\hat{x}:\mathcal{Y}\rightarrow\mathcal{\hat{X}}} E[d(X,\hat{x}(Y))]
\end{align}

---

A "proof sketch" of the more general case (without assuming finite alphabets) is this: For each $y \in \mathcal{Y}$ and $\hat{x} \in \mathcal{\hat{X}}$ we have
\begin{align}
E[d(X,\hat{X})|Y=y,\hat{X}=\hat{x}] &= E[d(X,\hat{x})|Y=y,\hat{X}=\hat{x}]\\
&\overset{(a)}{=} E[d(X,\hat{x})|Y=y]\\
&\geq \inf_{c \in \mathcal{\hat{X}}} E[d(X,c)|Y=y]
\end{align}
where (a) uses the Markov property $X\rightarrow Y\rightarrow \hat{X}$. 
Now for each $y \in \mathcal{Y}$, define $c(y) \in \mathcal{\hat{X}}$ as a particular minimizer of $E[d(X,c)|Y=y]$ over $c \in \mathcal{\hat{X}}$ (assuming the minimizer exists for simplicity, and breaking ties deterministically).  So the right-hand-side of the above inequality chain is $E[d(X, c(Y))|Y=y]$ and thus 
$$ E[d(X,\hat{X})|Y=y, \hat{X}=\hat{x}] \geq E[d(X,c(Y))|Y=y]$$
This holds for all $y \in \mathcal{Y}$ and $\hat{x} \in \mathcal{\hat{X}}$ and so 
$$ E[d(X,\hat{X})|Y, \hat{X}] \geq E[d(X,c(Y))|Y]$$
Taking expectations of both sides and using iterated expectations gives
\begin{align}
E[d(X,\hat{X})] &\geq E[d(X,c(Y))]\\
&\overset{(a)}{\geq} \inf_{\hat{x}:\mathcal{Y}\rightarrow\mathcal{\hat{X}}}E[d(X,\hat{x}(Y))]
\end{align}
where (a) holds because $c(y)$ is just a particular deterministic function from $\mathcal{Y}$ to $\mathcal{\hat{X}}$.

[see comments below for some pesky measurability details.]

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer it is very helpful. I have two quick question about the general part, I don't see why $E[d(X,\hat X)|Y,\hat X]\geq \inf_c E[d(X,c)|Y,\hat X]$ is true in general (for discrete or continuous it is trivial). My second question is about if the minimizer doesn't exists, then for every $y$ there is a sequence of $c_n$ converging to the $\inf$, this defines a sequence of functions $c_n:\mathcal Y\rightarrow \hat{\mathcal X}$ that converges to the second $\inf$ right ? So this ends the proof in the general case.

Comment: @P.Quinton : (+1) Yes those are tricky details.  I have edited my proof to help resolve the first question.  I have called it a "proof sketch" as there are pesky residual details: (i) Formally $\inf_{\hat{x}:\mathcal{Y}\rightarrow\mathcal{\hat{X}}}$ is over all deterministic functions $\hat{x}$ that result in measurable $d(X,\hat{x}(Y))$; (ii) the choice of $c(y)$ (or $c_n(y)$ when a minimizer does not exist) must be done while respecting measurability so expectations make sense; (iii) I have freely moved between expectations of the type $E[W|Z]$ and $E[W|Z=z]$ (for all $z$).

Comment: (i) Agreed. (ii),(iii) I think this can be solved, the inequality $\mathbb E[A|B]\geq \inf_b \mathbb E[A|B=b]$ almost surely should be provable easily, then $\mathbb E[d(X,\hat X)|Y,\hat X]\geq \inf_{c\in\mathcal E} \mathbb E[d(X,\hat X)|Y,\hat X=c(Y)]=\inf_{c\in \mathcal E} \mathbb E[d(X,c(Y))|Y]$, where $\mathcal E$ is the set of $\mathcal Y\rightarrow \hat{\mathcal X}$ measurable functions.